# Can I cache/store larger files within my native Iphone App

Tags: iphone, ipad, synchronization, download

We are looking to write an app that can locally store short videos and pdfs from the server for offline viewing.  Is this possible?  If so, how much storage capacity am I allowed.

So, can I pull down 1GB of video to view later in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Up to the storage capacity of the device.
3. Yes.

Note iOS offers separate Temporary, Cache and Documents folders for storage. You should aim to use the Temporary or Caches folder for storage because the Documents folder is backed up when syncing with iTunes, which is very slow if there are large files to transfer.

Comment: Just to be clear.  The app wouldn't have these videos/content when installed.  They would need to be downloaded or synchronized when new video is ready on the server.  Still good.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can store things in NSUserDefaults or File System